# Would I be considered a native English speaker?

Tags: word-usage

I'm currently 16 and I've been wondering if my English is considered as "native" English and the reason why I'm currently questioning this is because I'm currently creating a Curriculum.

I'm a Brit brought up in Spain that has been brought speaking both English and Spanish.

I studied in a Spanish school and have Spanish friends, but I also have British friends, and apart from when I'm speaking with the Spaniards, I think and speak in English.

Comment: You're bilingual, huge asset, and if one of your parents is English, born and bred,  that would be worth mentioning too.

Comment: Related (possible dupes): [How to describe someone who speaks English like a native](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69717/8019), [What is a 'native speaker 'of English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69717/8019)

Comment: What do you speak with your parents? That (or those if more than one) is almost universally your native language. When you stub your toe, what language do you swear in? When you count to ten in your head, what language do you do it in? Most likely your native language.